# Eclipse Mars, AngularJS and nodeJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, eclipse, server

I want your help to understand how node.js and angular.js work on eclipse.

I have Eclipse Mars and I want to run my Angularjs project on a local server (localhost:8080) but i don't know how to do it.

I followed the configuration of angularjs et nodejs on eclipse here : https://techanand.wordpress.com/2014/03/09/how-to-install-and-configure-angularjs-in-eclipse/

Thank you.

Comment: You don't have to have Eclipse to run node js apps. Just run 'node app.js' from console.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know but i want to run it from eclipse.. I think I need another tools like Nodeclipse or something else..

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS Eclipse uses node.js because it is required to execute tern.js the JavaScript inference engine which provides powerful completion, hover, hyperlink... for JavaScript

AngularJS project is a web application which requires a server (Jetty, Tomcat, node.js, etc). It seems that in your case, you have an HTTP server written in node.js, in other words your project is a node.js application

If you wish to have a Run/Debug launch for a node.js file, you can:

- install [JEE Eclipse Neon](https://eclipse.org/downloads/) when it will be available (in this june 2016)
- install [Webclipse](https://www.genuitec.com/products/webclipse/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this similar to Nodeclipse ?